# If $g\geq2$ is an integer, then $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{g^{n^{2}}} $ and $ \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{g^{n!}}$ are irrational

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, irrational-numbers

How do we show that if $g \geq 2$ is an integer, then the two series $$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{g^{n^{2}}} \quad  \ \text{and} \ \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{g^{n!}}$$ both converge to irrational numbers.

Well, i tried to see what happens, if they converge to a rational but couldn't get anything out it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Both are transcendental numbers. This follows from Roth's theorem on the rate of approximations to irrational numbers by rationals. See also this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10327/0-246810121416-is-it-a-algebraic-number/). The key concept is "irrationality measure", see for example this [entry](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IrrationalityMeasure.html) from MathWorld.

Comment: Dear Andres, At least for the second number, probably Liouvill'e's original Diophantine approximation result is enough.  (I mention this just because it is a lot easier than Roth's theorem.)  Best wishes,

Comment: @Matt E : Oh, sure. The mention of Roth's theorem was specifically to address the first series.

Answer (score 20):

The numbers are irrational, as they are infinite non-repeated "decimal" numbers in base-$g$.

Comment: ALthough that seems intuitively true, I only remember that repeating decimals implied rationality but have not seen how to show non-repeating decimals implies irrationality

Comment: @Arjang: This is a well known fact. If $(b,g) = 1$, then for some $m$ we have $g^m = 1 \mod b$. This gives $g^m \times \frac{a}{b} = (bk+1) \times \frac{a}{b} = ka + \frac{a}{b}$, which implies a repeating representation for $\frac{a}{b}$.

Answer (score 9):

Just for the record: the usual proof of irrationality is as follows (say for the first sum). Suppose that the sum is $p/q$. Multiply by $qg^{n^2}$, where $n$ is "big enough". We get that $$\sum_{m > n} \frac{q}{g^{m^2-n^2}}$$ is an integer. However, the latter is bounded by the geometric series $$q \sum_{t > 0} g^{-Nt} = \frac{q}{g^N} \cdot \frac{1}{1-g^{-N}} = \frac{q}{g^N-1},$$ where $N = (n+1)^2 - n^2 = 2n+1$. When $n$ is big enough, $q/(g^N-1) < 1$, contradiction.

This proofs works for any series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\prod_{i=1}^n a_i}$$ where the non-zero integers $a_i$ satisfy $|a_i| \rightarrow \infty$.