# Show that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty 10^{-k!}$ is not algebraic

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

> *Exercise:* Show that the number $\sum_{k=1}^\infty 10^{-k!} = 0.110001000\ldots$ is not an algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$.

I don't know how to start, can you give me any hints? Thank you!

Comment: If you were assigned this exercise then EITHER you are expected to be very very clever OR someone wanted to assign a problem exceeding your ability OR there was some relevant theorem or the were some relevant theorems stated shortly before you were assigned this problem, that you are expected to use.  The last possibility is the usual thing.  So tell us what those theorems are if you can. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: There is a discussion of this topic in the Wikipedia article on [Liouville numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_number).

Comment: @MJD: Yes, that looks promising.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17310. In fact Andres Caicedo's answer there answers your question.

Comment: If I remember it correctly (from Ivan Niven "Real Numbers") a rough sketch of the proof not using any deep theorems 'is: Assume $\alpha$ to be algebraic. Let $f$ be an integer polynomial (of smallest degree) that has $\alpha$ as a root. Let $\alpha_n = \sum^n10^{-k!}$ be approximations to $\alpha$. Study $f(\alpha) - f(\alpha_n)$ in two different ways (1) it is $-f(\alpha_n)$ 2) using $f(x)-f(y) = (x-y) \cdots$) and try to derive a contradiction.

Comment: I found a copy of the proof I mentioned above [here](http://users.auth.gr/siskakis/Niven-NumbersRationalAndIrrational.pdf). See page 112-122 (in the PDF, it's page 103-113 in the book). btw the outline of the proof I gave above seems correct in case you want to see if you can figure it out yourself.

Comment: The Wikipedia page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_number has a full proof of it.